# Windows Snipping Tool default screen selection

Tags: windows, images, snipping

With Windows Snipping Tool i'm able to select an area in my screen and save the image. Is it possible to set a default selection-size?

I'm trying to auto-screenshot a specific area of my screen and save the image.

Comment: Have you tried the windows macro recorders? May be they will be able to do the job. Post your efforts to avoid "down" votes

Comment: @Prasanna I used "freelabs Macro Recorder" and it has several major issues. Mouse over flash video is slow & it doesn't work with keyboard macros (opening start menu). I'm not liking this. Now I'm suggesting the AHK-route but I don't know the scripts.

Comment: After trying out Jitbit Macro Recorder the problems we're solved (flash/keyboard), but I don't seem to like this very much. I would prefer a scripting language route such as AHK but I don't know the scripts for my task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible with the native snipping tool (add this to the list of things I wish it could do, like print directly.) You may want to look into third party options like [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/).

Comment: I want to avoid specific-alternatives as i'm trying to find universal routes to EVERYTHING. AHK seems to makes sense for my taste, but I don't know any snipping tool scripts.

Answer (score 0):

### Quick Answer (TL;DR)

- create a default image size by using a transparent overlay SizerWindow
- place the SizerWindow over the desired image and use `SnippingTool :: New :: WindowSnip`
- the screenshot size will be constrained to match the size of the SizerWindow

### Detailed Answer

#### Context

- MSFT windows, win7, win10
- windows snipping tool

#### Problem

- **Use-case scenario:**

  - user176540 wants to create screenshots with default windows snipping tool
  - user176540 wants a default size (e.g., so multiple screenshots can all be exactly the same height and width)
  - user176540 does not want to use manual RectangularSnip, because that is too inexact and error-prone
- Windows SnippingTool does not come with a default image size option, but it is possible to emulate that using a transparent overlay SizerWindow

#### Solution

- create a default (uniform) image size by using a transparent overlay SizerWindow (a separate app)
- place the SizerWindow over the desired image and use `SnippingTool :: New :: WindowSnip`
- the screenshot size will be constrained to match the size of the SizerWindow
- save the image and repeat until you are done taking screenshots

#### Pitfalls

- You will have to obtain or create a separate app that is capable of presenting a resizable transparent window (SizerWindow)
- The results will be better if the SizerWindow does not have any superfluous UI elements, as those can distract and confuse readers

#### See also

- NOTE: links here do not constitute an endorsement of any product or tool

  - this is just a small sampling of possible options
  - numerous other options exist
- LiceCap

  - [pro] can act as a transparent overlay SizerWindow
  - [pro] simple to install and use
  - [pro] capable of capturing animated GIF
  - [con] has superfluous UI elements (app logo and buttons)
  - [LiceCap](https://licecap.en.softonic.com/)
- AutoIT

  - [pro] general purpose windows addon that can create a SizerWindow
  - [pro] capable of SizerWindow with zero superfluous UI elements
  - [pro] a sample SizerWindow script already exists
  - [con] general-purpose scripting tool harder to learn for beginners
  - [con] perhaps overkill if you just want a SizerWindow and you do not want to use or write scripts
  - [AutoIt Download](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/downloads/)
  - [AutIt SizerWindow script](https://github.com/dreftymac/trypublic/blob/master/lab2022/autoit_sizer_window/autoit_screenshot_sizer.au3)